# Linear action of group $G$ on vector space $V$

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, group-actions

Let $p$ be a prime number, and let $G$ be a finite group whose order is a power of $p$. Let $F$ be a field with characteristic $p$, and $V$ a nonzero vector space over $F$ equipped with linear action of $G$.( That is, we have an action $G\times V\to V$ of the group $G$ on the set $V$, written $(g,v)\mapsto g\cdot v$, such that for all $g\in G$, the map $v\mapsto g\cdot v$ is an $F$-linear transformation of the $F$-vector space $V$. )

Prove that there exists a nonzero subspace $W\subset V$ such that $G$ acts trivially on $W$.

I know the basics about group action but I don't know how to even start. Any help will be great for me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: By trivial you mean $gw = w$, $\forall g \in G, \; w \in W$, right?

Comment: Yes. $gw=w$ for all $g\in G,w\in W$.

Comment: Here are some hints. $p$-groups have nontrivial centres, so $G$ has a central element $g$ of order $p$. Since $g^p-1=(g-1)^p$ in $F$, $\langle g \rangle$ has a nonzero fixed space $W$ in $V$, which is invariant under $G$. Now apply induction to the action of $G/\langle v \rangle$ on $W$.

Comment: Sorry, I meant apply induction to the (induced) action of $G/\langle g \rangle$ on $W$, not $G/\langle v \rangle$.

Comment: @DerekHolt How can an element of the group form subspace in $V$ ?

Comment: @nkh99 It can't - I never said that it could!